# Antenna connectivity test

Tags: rf, antenna, test, interconnect

could any one give idea how to test 5Ghz antenna for connectivity, i.e. that interconnections between antenna parts, and feeders are ok. On of my ideas was to use some MCU with touch library, because antenna has its own capacity. Using MCU we can check if this capacity is in suitable  range, by charging and discharging it. However, I believe that such solution can damage circuit , because of received arbitrary signal. How do you think, what problems such solution can cause? Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Is this test equipment or a feature inside a product? If a product then what sort of volume/cost are you looking for the solution?

Comment: This is test equipment. It will not be inside product.

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends what the definitions are for a valid `connection`. I assume you are talking about data transmission by `IEEE 802.11` (used by WiFi)? Then a MCU alone wouldn't be enough. You would require some kind of WiFi module and hook that up to the antenna. Then check if you receive data to be exactly the same, as the data that was sent by the transmitter. Whatever the transmitter may be: router, notebook, smartphone...

Edit:
If you would still go about charging its capacitance, I would consider the RC time, and use a comparator to see how long it takes for the comparator to output a high(er than) signal using the MCU. The comparator will likely never output higher than upper rail voltage. So connect - of comparator to reference voltage, + to the antenna as being the capacitor and output of comparator to MCU digital in or so.

Comment: You are right, this is 802.11n antenna. However I need just to check soldering between antenna and pigtail, and that antenna parts are soldered together. For me additional module and equipment will be too extensive. I'd like to use some simple method for that reason.